# Insert row above specific cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering whether it is possible to use vba to solve my problem :

There is a column named Time, it contained various time value, starting from the earliest to the latest, like a schedule.
Like this
Name  Time
Mark  10:20
Tony  10:50
Alex  12:30
Sophie  13:35
Max    14:30
Sally  14:50

And I want to insert a row above 14:00, in this case, a new row between 13:35 and 14:30,like this
Name  Time
Mark  10:20
Tony  10:50
Alex  12:30
Sophie  13:35

Max    14:30
Sally  14:50

After that I want to insert specific text in the new row,like this
Name   Time
Mark   10:20
Tony   10:50
Alex   12:30
Sophie 13:35
XX     16:00
Max    14:30
Sally  14:50

Also I need to draw a border line above the new row, below is a picture, it may explain better of what I want to say

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR96J.jpg)

Hope someone can give me a hand

Comment: did you try to record a macro of yourself doing that manually? Then all you would have to do is edit the vba which will have all the syntax created for you. The key would be finding a reference to the cell you want, the code generator will probably reference it as "activecell" or something. You would want to do something like a loop where you test the "time" value of each cell in the loop until you come across the desired cell.

Comment: I did, but I am really new to this. I have no idea how to test the "time" value or find a reference to the cell I want just like you said......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will find the desired time (input: time), insert a row above that time, put a boarder above inserted line, and fill the blank cells with new content (var: colA, colB, colC).

This assumes that your time is in column C, the text you want to insert is in column A to C, and your boarder also goes from column A to C.

```
Sub InsertRow()

Dim time As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim colA As String
Dim colB As String
Dim colC As String

time = "FindTime"
colA = "Name1"
colB = "Value1"
colC = "Time1"

y = Application.Match(time, Columns(3), 0)
Rows(y).Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range(Cells(y - 1, "A"), Cells(y - 1, "C")).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble

Cells(y, 1) = colA
Cells(y, 2) = colB
Cells(y, 3) = colC

End Sub
```

Comment: I get this "Run-time error:'13' Type Mismatch"  error message when I run this Macro.....

Comment: Looks like this [ time = "FindTime" ] need a specific time value like "14:10",  but my original data does not come with 14:10 every time, sometimes it comes with "14:30" as the first time value after pm 01:00(13:00)

Comment: How is the time the blank row is inserted above determined?  Where are you getting the text to insert from?

Comment: Problem solved!!  
I add a new column with function "Left" to extract the hour value of "time" column, and use this "hour" value (for example: 14) to match.                                                   time = "14", colA = "Tom", colB = "XEF", colC = "16:00".  And it work perfectly, as 14 is an integer to detect. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Awesome Tony, glad it worked out man.  Keep up the good work.